# How to exclude Web Deployment Project from building when the configuration is Debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, msbuild

I have selected the configuration as 'Debug', and my WDP file has

```
Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' "
```

everywhere, so as I understood it shouldn't compile, but still is compiling.

What I'm doing wrong? I'm using Visual Studio 2008, if that matter.

In other words, how can I make that WDP only compiles when the selected configuration is Release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select Debug configuration, right click on the solution, select Configuration manager, and there in the list of projects the last column is named "Build" and it has checkboxes. You can check or uncheck each project. If a project is unchecked, it is not going to be built everything time you build/rebuild the solution.

[image: Configuration manager screenshot]